# How to build OpenEXR 2.2 using Visual Studio 14 2015 x64?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, cmake, 64-bit, openexr

I am using CMake 3.7.1. I want to build [OpenEXR](https://github.com/openexr/openexr) 2.2 using Visual Studio 2015 x64. The release version contains detailed build instructions:

> 1. Launch a command window, navigate to the IlmBase folder with  CMakeLists.txt,and type command:     setlocal    del /f CMakeCache.txt
>      cmake
>        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=
>        -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" 
>        ..\ilmbase
> 2. Navigate to IlmBase folder in Windows Explorer, open ILMBase.sln and build the solution. When it build successfully, right click 
>      INSTALL project and build. It will install the output to the path you
>      set up at the previous step.
> 3. Go to http://www.zlib.net and download zlib
> 4. Launch a command window, navigate to the OpenEXR folder with  CMakeLists.txt, and type command:        setlocal    del /f CMakeCache.txt
>      cmake 
>        -DZLIB_ROOT=
>        -DILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX=
>        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=
>        -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" ^
>        ..\openexr
> 5. Navigate to OpenEXR folder in Windows Explorer, open OpenEXR.sln and build the solution. When it build successfully, right click 
>      INSTALL project and build. It will install the output to the path you
>      set up at the previous step.

Step 1 to 2 work without a problem for me. The lib, dll and header files of IlmBase are stored in the "build" folder:

[image]

My executed instructions for Step 1 to 2:

```
wget.exe https://github.com/openexr/openexr/archive/v2.2.0.zip -OC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip
7za.exe x C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
del C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip
C:
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\IlmBase
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -HC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0 -BC:\build\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0 ^
setlocal
del /f CMakeCache.txt
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="..\ilmbase\build" -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\ilmbase
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --target INSTALL
```

Step 3 (downloading and building zlib-1.2.8) is also easy:

```
wget.exe http://zlib.net/zlib128.zip -OC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8.zip
7za.exe x C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
del C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8.zip
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -HC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8 -BC:\build\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8
C:
cd C:\build\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config Debug
mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib
mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\bin
copy Debug\zlibd.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\bin\zlibd.dll
copy Debug\zlibd.exp C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibd.exp
copy Debug\zlibd.ilk C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibd.ilk
copy Debug\zlibd.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibd.lib
copy Debug\zlibd.pdb C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibd.pdb
copy Debug\zlibstaticd.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibstaticd.lib
copy Release\zlib.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\bin\zlib.dll
copy Release\zlib.exp C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlib.exp
copy Release\zlib.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlib.lib
copy Release\zlibstatic.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8\lib\zlibstatic.lib
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
rmdir C:\build\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8 /S /Q
```

Now it comes to Step 4+5. I am executing the following statements:

```
cmake -DZLIB_ROOT="C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.8" ^
-DILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX="C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\IlmBase\build" ^
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="..\OpenEXR\build" ^
-G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ^
..\openexr
```

I am opening the openexr.sln and than I try to build IlmInf. There is one error: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515

[image]

Here is the error log:

```
4>------ Build started: Project: IlmImf, Configuration: Debug x64 ------ 
4>  Building Custom Rule C:/thirdparty/vs2015/x64/openexr-2.2.0/OpenEXR/IlmImf/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\CMakeFiles\generate.stamp is up-to-date. 
4>  Generating b44ExpLogTable.h 
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don not understand why I get this error. What am I doing wrong here?

BTW: My batch scripts used to build zlib and OpenEXR can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Vertexwahn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IlmImf tries to run b44ExpLogTable.exe which requires the Half.dll file located at the right place. When copying the Half.dll, etc. files to the right location everything works fine.

I use the following windows batch script to handle building OpenEXR and copying all the stuff to the right place:

**Build_openexr-2.2.0_Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64.cmd**

```
wget.exe https://github.com/openexr/openexr/archive/v2.2.0.zip -OC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip
7za.exe x C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
del C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0.zip
C:
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\IlmBase
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy" ^
-G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ^
 ..\ilmbase
setlocal
del /f CMakeCache.txt
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="..\deploy" -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..\ilmbase
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --target INSTALL
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR
setlocal
del /f CMakeCache.txt
cmake -DZLIB_ROOT="C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11" ^
-DILMBASE_PACKAGE_PREFIX="C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy" ^
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="..\deploy" ^
-G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ^
..\openexr

mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Half.dll          C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release\Half.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Iex-2_2.dll       C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release\Iex-2_2.dll 
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IexMath-2_2.dll   C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release\IexMath.2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IlmThread-2_2.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release\IlmThread-2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Imath-2_2.dll     C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Release\Imath-2_2.dll

mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Half.dll          C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo\Half.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Iex-2_2.dll       C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo\Iex-2_2.dll 
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IexMath-2_2.dll   C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo\IexMath.2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IlmThread-2_2.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo\IlmThread-2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Imath-2_2.dll     C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\RelWithDebInfo\Imath-2_2.dll

mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Half.dll          C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug\Half.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Iex-2_2.dll       C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug\Iex-2_2.dll 
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IexMath-2_2.dll   C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug\IexMath.2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\IlmThread-2_2.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug\IlmThread-2_2.dll
copy C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\deploy\lib\Imath-2_2.dll     C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\openexr-2.2.0\OpenEXR\IlmImf\Debug\Imath-2_2.dll

cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --target INSTALL
```

Building OpenEXR requires a prebuild zlib version. I build zlib using the following script:

**Build_zlib-1.2.11_Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64.cmd**

```
wget.exe http://zlib.net/zlib1211.zip -OC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11.zip
7za.exe x C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11.zip -oC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64
del C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11.zip
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -HC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11 -BC:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\build
C:
cd C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\build
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib
mkdir C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\bin
copy Debug\zlibd.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\bin\zlibd.dll
copy Debug\zlibd.exp C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibd.exp
copy Debug\zlibd.ilk C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibd.ilk
copy Debug\zlibd.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibd.lib
copy Debug\zlibd.pdb C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibd.pdb
copy Debug\zlibstaticd.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibstaticd.lib
copy Release\zlib.dll C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\bin\zlib.dll
copy Release\zlib.exp C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlib.exp
copy Release\zlib.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlib.lib
copy Release\zlibstatic.lib C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\lib\zlibstatic.lib
copy zconf.h C:\thirdparty\vs2015\x64\zlib-1.2.11\zconf.h
```

You can also download these scripts from  https://github.com/Vertexwahn/Percdems

Comment: But which is the appropriate directory? 
Shouldn't VS be able to locate it if it is located in an Additional Library Directory? (In my case it doesn't...) Copying it to the directory of the executable helps to run the exe itself, but it seems that the executable is started from elsewhere when called as a buildstep

Comment: @StefanReinhardt I edited my post to make clear where the appropriate directory is.

Comment: Ah cool thanks for the script, helps a lot to automize the build process

Comment: Is `cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config Release` on purpose in `Build_openexr-2.2.0_Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64.cmd` ? or the first one should be in `Debug`?

Comment: @Muhammad Muaz - that was a mistake - I fixed it in the posting

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer was not working for me with OpenEXR 2.3.0. Below is a batch file that works for me on Windows 10 with VS 2015 x64.
You need wget.exe, 7za.exe and the contents of the following batch in the same folder.
Note that I've disabled the Python libs because I don't need them and I don't have Python installed.

```
rem ### ZLIB ###

wget.exe http://zlib.net/zlib1211.zip -O.\zlib-1.2.11.zip
7za.exe x .\zlib-1.2.11.zip -o.\
del .\zlib-1.2.11.zip

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
cmake -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -H.\zlib-1.2.11 -B.\zlib-1.2.11\build

cd zlib-1.2.11\build
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo
cd..
mkdir lib
mkdir bin
cd build
copy Debug\zlibd.dll ..\bin\zlibd.dll
copy Debug\zlibd.exp ..\lib\zlibd.exp
copy Debug\zlibd.ilk ..\lib\zlibd.ilk
copy Debug\zlibd.lib ..\lib\zlibd.lib
copy Debug\zlibd.pdb ..\lib\zlibd.pdb
copy Debug\zlibstaticd.lib ..\lib\zlibstaticd.lib
copy Release\zlib.dll ..\bin\zlib.dll
copy Release\zlib.exp ..\lib\zlib.exp
copy Release\zlib.lib ..\lib\zlib.lib
copy Release\zlibstatic.lib ..\lib\zlibstatic.lib
copy zconf.h ..\zconf.h

cd..\..

rem ### OPENEXR ### 

wget.exe https://github.com/openexr/openexr/archive/v2.3.0.zip -O.\openexr-2.3.0.zip
7za.exe x .\openexr-2.3.0.zip -o.
del .\openexr-2.3.0.zip
cd openexr-2.3.0\
setlocal
del /f CMakeCache.txt
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="%~dp0openexr-2.3.0" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="%~dp0zlib-1.2.11" -DOPENEXR_BUILD_PYTHON_LIBS=0
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Debug -- /maxcpucount:8
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release -- /maxcpucount:8
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config RelWithDebInfo -- /maxcpucount:8

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

*Steps to fix error MSB6006 "cmd.exe":*

1. Make sure you have built **ilmbase.sln** solution and after that Build "**INSTALL**" part of the **ilmbase**. As result you`ll find **lib** and **include** folders in **ilmbase** directory.
2. Open **Advanced system settings** and your path ...**\ilmbase-2.2.0\lib;** to the end of "**Path**" system variable. Close Advanced system settings.
3. Restart Visual Studio and rebuild **openexr.sln**

Answer (score 0):

On **OpenEXR 2.3.0** there seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/openexr/openexr/issues/355) with *IlmImf* CMake file.

The proposed workaround (search and replace `OPENEXR_PACKAGE_PREFIX` with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`) works fine in my case.

In my case I simply call

`sed -i "s/OPENEXR_PACKAGE_PREFIX/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX/g" ./OpenEXR/IlmImf/CMakeLists.txt`

before running `cmake` (git for windows)